# Safari Preferences plist not changing on mac 10.9 from User Defaults

Tags: macos, caching, safari, osx-mavericks, preference

I am facing problem with Preference Caching in Mac while changing "Block cookies and other website data:" form privacy. I tried user defaults to change the preferences. When "Never" option were selected its changing to "From third parties and advertisers". But if "Always" selected changes it's not working. OSX version is 10.3

defaults write com.apple.Safari com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2StorageBlockingPolicy 1

defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitStorageBlockingPolicy 1

Followed same steps given in this link http://hotdigitalnews.com/how-to-tackle-defaults-not-sticking-in-mavericks/

Comment: Finally I am able to change cookies preferences after many days researches.

Comment: *"mac 10.9...OSX version is 10.3"* doesn't make any sense, it can't be both. I think you mean your MacOS version is 10.9? If so please fix the question and title.

Answer (score 0):

-(IBAction)allowCookies:(id)sender {

```
[self quitApplicationIfRunning:@"com.apple.Safari"];
[self setCookies];

NSString *text =nil;
NSString *commandString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"defaults write com.apple.WebFoundation NSHTTPAcceptCookies 'always' "];
text = [self runAsCommand:commandString];
NSLog(@"text %@",text);
[self manageCookies:0];
```

}

-(void)setCookies{

```
NSLog(@"Cookies has been changed %lu",[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookieAcceptPolicy]);
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]  setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NSHTTPCookieManagerAcceptPolicyChangedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
```

}

-(void)manageCookies:(short)option{

```
NSString *commandString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"defaults write com.apple.Safari com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2StorageBlockingPolicy -int %d",option];

NSString *text = [self runAsCommand:commandString];
NSLog(@"text %@",text);

commandString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitStorageBlockingPolicy -int %d",option];

text = [self runAsCommand:commandString];
NSLog(@"text %@",text);
```

}

- (NSString*)runAsCommand:(NSString *)string {

  NSPipe* pipe = [NSPipe pipe];

  NSTask* task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
  [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];
  [task setArguments:@[@"-c", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string]]];
  [task setStandardOutput:pipe];

  NSFileHandle* file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
  [task launch];

  return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[file readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  }

Comment: tried all three default writes : defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitStorageBlockingPolicy -int 1
defaults write com.apple.Safari com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2StorageBlockingPolicy -int 1
defaults write com.apple.WebFoundation 'NSHTTPAcceptCookies' -string 'current page' still not working. Even after restarting browser. Any help?